# Seg Fault With libjpeg

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, libjpeg

I can't make any sense of the segmentation fault I'm getting out of the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <jpeglib.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    FILE*                   outfile;
    JSAMPLE*                row_pointer;
    struct jpeg_error_mgr   jerr;
    long long int           *w, *h;

    setSomePointers(w, h);

    printf( "%lld  %lld\n", *w, *h);
}
```

Commenting out any one of the first three declarations will fix it...

Oddly, the following code works:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <jpeglib.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    FILE*                   outfile;
    JSAMPLE*                row_pointer;
    struct jpeg_error_mgr   jerr;
    long long int           w, h;

    setSomePointers(&w, &h);

    printf( "%lld  %lld\n", w, h);
}
```

Is there something strange happening, or do I need to hit some C tutorials?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is totally undefined behavior - you dereference uninitialized pointers.

The actual problem is in

```
printf( "%lld  %lld\n", *w, *h);
```

The other things are just declarations. You should not dereference `w` and `h`, as they are not initialized at all. This has nothing to do with commenting/uncommenting any of the first (3) lines.

Comment: Sorry, in my actual code there a lot of stuff happens between the declarations and the print statement. I figured I'd chop as much out as I could. Does it make sense that this gives a seg fault, while getting rid of any of the first three declarations actually produces some numbers?

Comment: It's my understanding that there's nothing terribly wrong with uninitialized values like this in C. They might be meaningless (whatever junk happened to be in memory before I got here, or something). You can replace the uninitialized `long long int*`s with `long long int` and the problem is the same.

Comment: Are you sure, that `w` and `h` are initialized? You know, an advise - try to initialize all of these variables, just in case. To see what will happen. Commenting lines doesn't make any sense. Or, paste your code somewhere, to be able to take a loot at it.

Comment: It still breaks with initialized pointers. It's fine when they're not pointers (initialized or not). Could this be an Ubuntu problem?

Comment: I'm tempted to just power on ignoring the issue since the second code block I posted works... However I'm curious, concerned and wondering if there may be a bug the needs reporting to someone.

Comment: I don't think it's Ubuntu problem. Did you try to use a debugger? Also, the second code block, you've posted is **totally** different from the first. In your second `printf`, you print numbers, not dereferencing pointers. So, if you function `setSomePointers` leave uninitialized some of the two parameters, you'll have no problem - `printf` will print garbage, but will not crash (in the second case)

Comment: I think I _am_ confused about some C details. Is dereferencing a pointer not equivalent to using the plain data type?

Comment: Well, it's kinda different. First, the easier part - using numbers (your second code) - when you declare a variable (on the stack), for example - when the two variables are numbers, they are uninitialized. When you try to print them - nothing that bad happens - the value of these numbers are some random, so it's not a big deal - you'll just print "garbage". Using pointers is different - when you have an uninitialized pointer, it points to a random place in the memory. When you try to print **the pointer** it's (almost) the same as printing a number - you'll print some address, and ...

Comment: nothing else. The problem comes when dereferencing uninitialized pointers. And here's why - the uninitialized pointer points (as I already said) to a random place in the memory. Then when you do `*w` (for example), you **take the value, that is written in the pointed place**. So, as the pointer could point anywhere, it could point to the memory of some other process, so you cannot change (or anything) a memory, that is not "yours" .

Comment: Arght, this is too long, but one of the most complicated things in C are the pointers. Anyway. So, this is **undefined behavior**, because anything could happen. If the pointer points to e accessible memory - it's even worse, because this could break something and a crash is preferable. If it points to unaccessible memory - crash (memory violation ). I hope that helper a little.

Comment: It helps very much. Is _initializing a pointer with a value_ essentially a two-part process? 1) `malloc` some memory, and 2) set the value?

Comment: What I could advise - always initialize the pointers to `NULL`. This will give you the opportunity to check if, after the execution of `setSomePointers`, the pointers are correctly set or they are not touched. `int *w = NULL; /* pass w to a function .. */ if( NULL != w ) printf(..) else printf( "NULL pointer" );` Or something like this. You'd really need a book or C tutorial :)

Comment: So it's quite an interesting coincidence that the twenty or so times I compiled and ran this thing produced seg faults with all of the initializations, and no seg fault with any of the initializations missing...

Comment: Well, it is, when you allocate some memory. But if you don't need it, you could just initialize it with NULL. Also, your first example (with the pointers) expects that `setSomePointers` will take double pointes, will change the `w` and `h` pointers and make the point to a memory, allocated with `malloc` (or to point to a static numnbers). If `setSomePointers` does not do this, you got undefined behavior.